# WPF XAML xmlns clarification.

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to know what is the difference between two definitions. 
I have a class in C# that calls AutoAlgorithms in namespace CalibrationControls and i want to know how to include it as part of the XAML.

xmlns:autoAlgo="clr-namespace:CalibrationControls.AutoAlgorithms"
xmlns:autoAlgo="clr-namespace:CalibrationControls.AutoAlgorithms;assembly=CalibrationControls.AutoAlgorithms"

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you can omit the `assembly` part if the namespace is defined within the same assembly, and you usually declare the namespace in the root element.

Look here for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx